# How to copy a Google Sheets chart to Google Documents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Apparently Google Docs is able to embed charts from Google Sheets (I mean "normal" range-based charts and not ones from Google Charts). So, if I change the chart colours for example, I can update these changes in Google Docs.

Unfortunately, Google Docs does not have script recorder features and it doesn't help when I record the copy / paste from Google Sheets (of course, I only intended to use the record feature for help).

I believe I should embed the chart as any object via its url (at least its id part). I'm aware of method such as `appendImage()` (`Body` class), but I cannot find equivalent for charts.

Can anyone give me some guidance using **Google Apps Script** (not from API)?

[Link to the Google Docs reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body)

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to get the chart from sheets and insert it to the Document:

```
function getChart() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_ID').getSheets()[0]
  var documentBody = DocumentApp.openById('DOCUMENT_ID').getBody();
  var arr_charts = sheet.getCharts()
  documentBody.appendImage(arr_charts[0].getBlob());
}
```

That will get you the chart as an image on the Document.

To update it you can create a function that is triggered when the sheet is modified, [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite), that gets the chart from the document and it replaces it with the new one.

Comment: Thanks for your example. I already came across the "blob" format reading the Google documentation, but never really used it in practise. I don't think it really corresponds to what I'm looking for, because when I manually copy / paste the chart I get a popup window asking if I want to link it to the spreadsheet or not. There is also a link button at the right-top of the chart.

Comment: It seems that there is not a direct method to do this. You can create a Feature Request for this feature on [Google Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640)